# Return a column that has one value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How can I find a column that has a constant/only one value?

For example, given this data I want to return column F.

```
ColumnA ....ColumnE  ColumnF
   1        Apple     Rob
   2        Orange    Rob
   3        banana    Rob
   4        Peach     Rob
   5        Pears     Rob
```

Comment: what do you want to return?

Comment: I want to return the location of Column F that only has Rob (only one value) in it out of the whole 20 columns I have.

Comment: With a formula you will need a helper row that has the unique count, many answers on that specific problem.  Then you can use MATCH to return where that row equals 1.

Comment: do you have the formula with the helper row?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1) = COUNTA(A:A)` as long as there's always a value in the first row...

Comment: @Tim Williams: I don't understand what it is doing

Comment: If the column only contains a single distinct value (and that value is present in row 1) then COUNTIF() will return how many instances of that value are in the column.  Since the column doesn't contain any other values then COUNTA() will return the same result and the formula evaluates to TRUE

Comment: Do I have to do this column by column or I can use this for a whole sheet and change the range?

Comment: If you enter in ColA and drag over it will adjust for each column.  If you want something more specific it would help to explain what you want to do with the result.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I made some changes to the range and then dragged the formula over for my columns and it worked :). Thanks much for all the effort and explanation on this.